# Getting a particular type string using regular expression in postgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to get a specific type to string from a jason column in the table using postgreSQL.

Here is the string snippet  and from it I am trying to get rate and $ amount as each row (e.g. CommentFOS rate $00.00)

```
Last 4  CommentsFOS rate $10.00  OT/HOL $20.00,  AP rate $30.00  OT/HOL $40.00
```

This is the query I have currently

```
select id,  
       regexp_matches(current_data->>'description', '..\w\/\w* \$[0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]','g') as rates
from table;
```

And the output I am getting is something like this

```
ID. rates
1   { OT/HOL $20.0}
1   { OT/HOL $40.0}
```

Also tried this query

```
select id, 
       regexp_matches(current_data->>'description', '\w*FOS \w* \$[0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]','g') as rates
from table;
```

the output I am getting from above sql is

```
ID. rates
1   { CommentsFOS rate $10.00}
```

But, Output I am expecting like this

```
ID. rates
1   { CommentsFOS rate $10.00}   
1   { OT/HOL $20.00}
1   { AP rate $10.00}
1   { OT/HOL $40.00}
```

Comment: What's a jason column?

Comment: A column named ->  description contains string type jason

Comment: Do you mean `JSON`? But  your strings aren't valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\S+(?:\s+rate)?\s+\$\d*\.?\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4RdFAd/1). *Details*:

- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+rate)?` - an optional sequence of one or more whitespaces and the word `rate`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `\d*\.?\d+` - zero or more digits, an optional `.` char, one or more digits.

See the Postgres demo:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(
    'Last 4  CommentsFOS rate $10.00  OT/HOL $20.00,  AP rate $30.00  OT/HOL $40.00',
    '\S+(?:\s+rate)?\s+\$\d*\.?\d+','g') as rates
```

Output:

[image]